# Can't delete apps that are no longer available in App Store

Tags: iphone, ios, itunes, applications

I have four apps that are no longer available in the App Store. They're not installed on my phone (which is fine). **Every time** I connect my iPhone to I get this message in iTunes: "Some of the apps in your iTunes library were not installed on the iPhone because one or more errors occurred."

[image: itunes error]

In iTunes I can search for the app and the icon is grayed out:

[image: gray]

Click Install does nothing.

I've searched for these apps on the App Store and they're not there. How do I remove all four of these apps to avoid getting that message when connecting my phone to my computer?

Comment: soon you will have enough points to do this your self, for now it is a free service from me :)

Comment: @Tetsujin – this has been going on for months, it has nothing to do with whether the store is down or not.

Comment: @Buscar웃 – I have no idea what you're talking about.

Comment: Posting the actual screen shots rather then just links :)

Comment: If you look at the "More Information", does it give you an error code?

Comment: @thedanielmatt - unfortunately, no. It takes me to this page: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201398

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apps didn't have .ipa files in my system, which may have been part of the problem. What I ended up doing was a search in iTunes (the global search at the upper right corner of the app) for each one. In the results, there is an icon with three dots, clicking on that icon brings up a contextual menu with the option to delete.

That error message I was getting before no longer appears after that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will resolve it, but you could try removing the .ipa files from your computer.

In Finder, navigate to "/Users/your name/Music/iTunes/iTunes Media/Mobile Applications"

From there, you can try removing the .ipa files.

Comment: Thanks for that. Sadly the apps don't have .ipa files in that folder. :/

Answer (score 0):

Just encountered the same problem. The files were likely removed from your computer but still present in the iTunes library. Deleting the apps from the library may be the solution you are looking for.